# CMS User Query with SearchKit

Tags: searchkit, cms-integration

The "Advanced Search" interface has the following option:

CMS User?
Yes No
Does the contact have a WordPress Account?

However, I have been unable to find a similar option in SearchKit. Is that functionality available in SearchKit?

Answer (score 2):

Making User accounts as base table is possible to check

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately that doesn't seem to allow finding CiviCRM users that don't yet have a CMS account.

Comment: If CMS ID is not empty will return all Civi contacts with CMS users. If CMS ID is empty will return all Civi contacts without CMS users